# Pan - zoom - orbit using Multi Touch - Unreal Engine -

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, blueprint

I would like to make a multi touch control for my camera

This camera should do:

**zoom in/out** when pinching

**orbit** when swiping

**pan** when swiping with 2 fingers.

Is there somebody who know some good examples/tutorials or give me some advice?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The best example I found was the [Strategy Game (Tower defense)](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Resources/SampleGames/StrategyGame/index.html) sample that comes with the Unreal Engine. It demonstrates an independent camera system in C++ that responds to touch gestures.

As a simplified but very similar approach you may find also find useful my [UE4TopDownCamera sample project](https://github.com/ntk4/UE4TopDownCamera) for a top down camera with:

1. **spread/pinch** or **mouse wheel up/down** for zoom in/out (implemented as dollying)
2. **swipe** with one finger for panning
3. on/off functionality to **lock on/follow** main character or freely move 
   camera.

Please notice that the gestures are not exactly the ones you described, as my requirements were different.

I'll soon upload some full explanation and a video on github.